# Strange js eval/template strings behaviour

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval, template-strings

Trying to answer a question in stackoverflow, I was doing some tests in my chrome console, and found the following case I am not able to understand.

```js
var vals = ['x','y','z'];
vals.forEach(val => { eval(`var ${val} = 1; console.log('${val} = ', ${val})`);});
```

How can javascript know when I am refering to ${val} as the val defined in "vals" array, and when I am refering to the value it has stored each value in that array?

I mean, why it does not log:

x = x;

y = y;

z = z;

or

1 = 1;

1 = 1;

1 = 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template string is evaluated *first*, outside of the context of your `eval`. So you've effectively done:

```
eval("var x = 1; console.log('x = ', x)");
eval("var y = 1; console.log('y = ', y)");
eval("var z = 1; console.log('z = ', z)");
```

Which of course is just printing each variable, along with it's value.

When using eval like that, it would be useful to replace it with a `console.log` to see what string is actually being sent through to the call:

```js
var vals = ['x','y','z'];
vals.forEach(val => { console.log('eval string:', `var ${val} = 1; console.log('${val} = ', ${val})`);});
```